# Converting Timespan to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, excel-interop, ole-automation

I am reading Excel worksheet data using C# and Microsoft.Office.Interop. The sheet contains some date values. When I am trying to read that value it is just giving the number (probably TimeSpan). I am having problem converting this number into DateTime.

Below is the code:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(((Range)ws.Cells[4, 1]).Value2.ToString());
```

Where `ws` is `Excel.WorkSheet`.

Can anybody explain how should I convert this number (`TimeSpan`) into `DateTime`?

Thanks for sharing your valuable time.

Comment: It could be giving you ticks which the datatime has a contructor for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do the following

```
double d = double.Parse(((Range)ws.Cells[4, 1]).Value2.ToString());

DateTime conv = DateTime.FromOADate(d);
```

Comment: Verified with the OP's test data of 40269 = Apr 1 2010: `var when = DateTime.FromOADate(40269);`

Comment: Greco -- did you change your name? I'll update my answer if so :)

Answer (score 9):

Use the following:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime().Add( TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( 1304686771794 ) )
```

Answer (score 6):

It all depends on what the number looks like ;p That is typically the offset in some interval, into some epoch - for example seconds since 1 Jan 1970. So try, for example:

```
var when = new DateTime(1970,1,1).AddSeconds(number);
```

and then try `AddMilliseconds(number)`, `AddTicks(number)` etc until the date matches.

Comment: Thanks Marc for your quick reply. Can you please tell me what should i consider if i m getting 40269 for Apr/1/2010.

Comment: @IrfanRaza - in that case @Greco has the answer; `var when = DateTime.FromOADate(40269);`

Answer (score 2):

This is just icing: Excel represents dates as [OLE automation dates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx). These values are floating point numbers, the integer part of which is the number of days after midnight, 30 Dec 1899. Or before, if it's negative. Greco's answer gives you the best way to convert :)